# Running netcat through vb forms

Tags: vb.net, netcat

i am trying to run netcat to programatically transfer a file using vb 2010 express. I am getting this error in console window :
`nc: forward host lookup failed:h_errno 11004: NO_DATA`
When i try to run the same code through batch file it works:

```
nc -l -p 3334 < some.exe
```

I have given a simple button and tried with the following codes:

```
'Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo
    'p.FileName = "Cmd.exe"
    'p.Arguments = "nc -l -p 3334 < RADTools.exe"
    'Process.Start(p)
    Process.Start("nc.exe", "nc -l -p 3334 < RADTools.exe")
```

please help

Comment: Don't repeat "nc" in the arguments.

Comment: Thanks and now the error is:`<: forward host lookup failed:h_errno 11004: NO_DATA` actually i had this problem ! Sorry.

Comment: Anyone listening or not? Please!